# Documentation/Spec for Flash's XFL layout?

Tags: flash

Has anyone found an official spec or documentation on the XFL file layout?

Are there any design tools in existence or planned that can create XFL files? (Besides the official Adobe Flash Professional program)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477212/where-is-the-documentation-for-adobe-xfl-flash-interchange-format

Comment: Sadly the answer still appears to be: There isn't any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a duplicate of the Stack Overflow question, *[Where is the documentation for Adobe XFL Flash interchange format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477212/where-is-the-documentation-for-adobe-xfl-flash-interchange-format)*, in which there is a statement from 2008 saying Adobe "intends" to release the documentation.

It also links to *[What's the meaning of the non numerical values in the XFL's edge definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077200/whats-the-meaning-of-the-non-numerical-values-in-the-xfls-edge-definition)* which has some details on the drawing commands present in the format.